# Angular custom form control - how to access the parent ngForm instance if there is one

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom control using ControlValueAccessor, and my control is in a form with a bunch of material input controls.

The material inputs show the red validation underline in 3 cases.

1. the control has been touched and is invalid
2. the control is dirty and invalid
3. the form containing the control has been submitted and the control is invalid

I want to mimic this behavior in my custom control. I've used the injector to get a reference to the NgControl which lets me determine if the control is touched/dirty and invalid. But I can't figure out how to access the parent NgForm in a generic way to determine if it is submitted.

I don't want to explicitly pass it into my component, and I shouldn't need to since it isn't being explicitly passed to material input either yet that control is able to determine if the form has been submitted.

How do I get a hold of the parent forms submitted state?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding it in the injector, had to grab the FormGroupDirective

```
const formgroup: FormGroupDirective = this.injector.get(FormGroupDirective, null);
```

The directive has a submitted property I was able to use

Comment: I'm surprised that the article from angular material about implementing a custom form control didn't take care of the form submission. It's not fully usable otherwise.. and that's my implementation of a country autocomplete with your solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxu8rz-2xjnod?file=src/app/country-input/country-input.component.ts